# I want to convert the script from ibmnetezza to MSSQL

Tags: azure-synapse

I Am tring to convert by using Azure Synpase pathway but it's not working.Plz any one help me with that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have netezza view scripts. I want to convert those View script into MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Pathway is a new tool currently in preview which can look at  existing ibmnetezza script attempt to convert it to MSSQL and flag up errors.

Download the tool and run it against your Netezza installation. Start here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/synapse-pathway/azure-synapse-pathway-overview?view=azure-sqldw-latest